# SignOutAsync Not Signing Out

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm currently creating a web api for a mobile app. I've managed to sign the user in but now when I sign the user out, it doesn't seem to work.

I've read in other posts that you need to redirect the user in order to sign them out? I don't think i can do this as the client is an app on a phone (Let me know if I've misunderstood)

StartUp:

```cs
public class StartUp
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        ...

        services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AccountContext>()
            .AddSignInManager()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        ...

    }
}
```

Account Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]"), ApiController)]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    public SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager;

    public AccountSecurityController(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
    {
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }
    ...

    [HttpGet("logout")]
    public async Task logout()
    {
        await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    }
}
```

I've sent messages to the web api using postman. I made a post request and appended the session cookie in the header.
If I send the request twice they both seem the get through. I'm expecting the second attempt to be rejected and postman should show a 401 error.

Comment: I think you need to show us signInManager.

Comment: Its just the default sign in manager. I've modified the example to show this